# Jquery How to trigger function on without specifying events in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of items and can be removed by clicking.

I need the first item to be the highlight only when there is one item on the list.
I have tried to do that by the click event. **However, would it be possible to do it without .click()?** (or any other events). The reason is that this list is dynamically interacting with other lists that the list item may change by other functions.

In other words, the list is dynamically changing, could jquery keep checking whether there is only one item on the list (without specifying specific event trigger)?

```
<ul id="container">
<li>1</li>
<li class="fixed">2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li class="fixed">4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>

$('#container').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
  $(this).remove();
});


$('#container').click(function(){
  if ($('#container').children().length == 1) {
    $("#container li:first-child" ).css( "background-color", "#fff2ac" );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this purely with CSS with a rule that checks if the `li` is both the `:first-child` AND the `:last-child` -

```css
.container li:first-child:last-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h5>List With Many Items</h5>
<ul class="container">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="fixed">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="fixed">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>

<h5>List With One Item</h5>
<ul class="container">
  <li>1</li>
</ul>


<h5>List With Two Items</h5>
<ul class="container">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="fixed">2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems not working when the list is changing from many items to one item. To elaborate, my list initially contains more one items, then items can be removed. I want the highlight to happen when there is only one item left...

Comment: If you put the css in the correct place, this should work.